# Page Directives Inherits

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, page-directives

i am having lots of trouble getting started today... i keep getting

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Webapp5.landing'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="landing.aspx.cs" Inherits="Webapp5.landing" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

here is my code behind....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Webapp5

{
    public partial class landing : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my page...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="landing.aspx.cs" Inherits="Webapp5.landing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i know i am missing something easy here.... but i just cant get seem to get this working?
any ideas on how to get this page to run?

Comment: Try Clean/Rebuilt solution. and see if the error goes away

Comment: i am running this on a live dev site.. but i just cant seem to get a new page started

Comment: Are you sure you are putting a compiled solution ?

Comment: Looks like you may be missing using statements if this is a adhoc file and you showed us everything in the .cs file.

Comment: there is nothing else in the files.. i am just trying to get a basic page to appear before i start building it...

Comment: Then add in the missing using statements. I don't exactly know what they are, but you should at least have `using System;` for the `EventArgs` declaration.

Comment: added the using statments

Comment: So they already were in the file or did you just add them to the file? Did you get the same error?

Comment: It sounds like you need to push your newly compiled DLLs to the live dev site (if this is a new page).